# interact with web pages with many hyperlinks and search for a specific name or phrase How?

Tags: string-manipulation, web-access, interoperability, hyperlink

I have this code that shows many hyperlinks

```
links = Import[
"http://www.liceobrainstorm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/", 
"Hyperlinks"]
```

Unfortunately some of them appear with the % symbol, I don't know why).

the idea is that once the list is obtained I can interact with it and show me only those that meet a criterion, for example for this example all those that say "MEDIO-B", but if you can download them in a particular directory it would be great.

Comment: Your code works fine. The `%c2%b0` you see in links is mostly because of `°` in file names. For filtering names, you could use `Select[links, StringContainsQ[#, "MEDIO-B", IgnoreCase -> True] &]`

Comment: Those are encoded URL's, use `URLDecode`. `links = Import["http://www.liceobrainstorm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/", "Hyperlinks"] // Map[URLDecode]`

Comment: To download `Select[links, StringContainsQ[#, "MEDIO-B", IgnoreCase -> True] &] // 
  URLDownload[#, "~/Downloads"] &;`. Replace `MEDIO-8` with whatever string you want to search for, replace `~/Downloads` with the name of the directory to download the files to.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi hi , thanks ,I'm trying to make it work like this, I'm also trying to ask for the directory, what am I doing wrong? url = Input ["enter url"] links = Import[url, "Hyperlinks"] // Map[URLDecode]; text = Input["enter text to download"] (Select[links,StringContainsQ[#,"Matem",IgnoreCase[Rule]True]&]) Select[links, StringContainsQ[#, text, IgnoreCase -> True] &] // URLDownload[#, "D:\\zmios"] &;
I need the same to choose the previously created directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Download for all months

```
(* e.g. http://www.liceobrainstorm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/ *)   
url = InputString["enter url"]; 

(* e.g. Matem *)
text = InputString["enter text to download"];

(* Choose directory for downloaded files *)
dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory", $HomeDirectory];

months = IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@ Range[12];

links = months // Map[Import[url <> # <> "/", "Hyperlinks"] &] // Flatten // Map[URLDecode];

selectedLinks = Select[links, StringContainsQ[#, text, IgnoreCase -> True] &]

If[FreeQ[dir, $Canceled], selectedLinks // URLDownload[#, dir] &, Print["Cancelled"]]
```

---

```
url = InputString["enter url"];

links = Import[url, "Hyperlinks"] // Map[URLDecode];

text = InputString["enter text to download"];

selectedLinks = Select[links, StringContainsQ[#, text, IgnoreCase -> True] &];

dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory", $HomeDirectory]

If[FreeQ[dir, $Canceled], selectedLinks // URLDownload[#, dir] &, Print["Cancelled"]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123959/discussion-on-answer-by-rohit-namjoshi-interact-with-web-pages-with-many-hyperli).